# Binding to a Listbox in tkinter doesn't seem to be working

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I'm trying to bind the items in my listbox to mouse button number 1 so that when i press it it prints "hi". However whenever i try to do it the code simply won't work. What happens is when i launch the program it will print "hi" once and then never again no matter how many times i click on the mouse button 1. Any suggestions? Thanks

```
            from tkinter import *

            class Applikation(Frame): 
                def __init__(self, master):

                    Frame.__init__(self,master)

                    self.master=master
                    self.rssList = Listbox(self.master, height=30, width=50) 
                    self.rssList.grid(row=1, column=0, rowspan=4, padx=10, pady=20)
                    self.rssList.bind("<Button-1>", print("hi"))


            rssReader = Tk()
            rssReader.title("Rss reader")
            rssReader.resizable(10, 10)
            app = Applikation(rssReader).grid()
            rssReader.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to pass the command as a reference without the `()` when binding to `<Button-1>`.

You can do so by either defining a separate function:

```
class Applikation(Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        ...
        self.rssList.bind("<Button-1>", self.print_hi)

    def print_hi(self,event):
        print ("hi")
```

Or use a `lambda` function:

```
self.rssList.bind("<Button-1>", lambda e: print("Hi"))
```

Comment: Thank you! Embarassing how long i tried to fix it without progress, maybe i'm just dumb cause looking it up didn't help, again, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The print() function only prints to the console, not to the GUI.

The way I solved this was to make a new method for the Applikation class, and call that in in rssList.bind.

Meaning:

```
class Applikation(Frame): 
    def __init__(self, master):
        #everything else here is fine
        self.rssList.bind("<Button-1>", self.say_hi)

    def say_hi(self, default=None):
        self.rssList.insert(END, "Hi")
#Keep everything else here the same
```